# jquery ajax submit only submitting first value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am submitting a form using jquery and ajax.  I have my first select menu and depending on the value of this select menu a div that contains a different menu will become visible.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <select required="" class="input-medium" id="foulTypes" name="foul" data-original-title="" title="">
            <option value="">Select Foul</option>
            <option value="85">AID - Aiding Runner</option>
            <option value="1">BAT - Illegal Bat</option>
            <option value="2">BBW - Block Below Waist</option>
            <option value="3">BOB - Blocking Out of Bounds</option>
            <option value="4">CHB - Chop Block</option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table
 <script>
     var foulTypes = $('#foulTypes');
     var select = this.value;
     foulTypes.change(function () {
        //We first disable all, so we dont submit data for more than 1 category
        $("#catDPI, #catILF, #catOPI, #catOH, #catDH, #catILD, #catUNS, #catUNR, #catTGT").hide().find(".category").attr("disabled", true);
        var $divSelectedCategory;
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            $divSelectedCategory = $("#catDPI");
            $('#catDPI').show();
        } else {
            $('#catDPI').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).val() == '85') {
          $divSelectedCategory = $("#catILF");
          $('#catILF').show();
        } else {
          $('#catILF').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).val() == '2') {
          $('#catOPI').show();
          $divSelectedCategory = $("#catOPI");
        } else {
          $('#catOPI').hide();
        }

        //We now enable only for the selected category        
        $divSelectedCategory.show().find(".category").attr("disabled", false).val('');
 });    
 </script>

  <div id="catDPI" style="display:none;">
      <select name="category" id="dpiCategory" class='category' style="width:210px;">
            <option value="Playing Through Receiver">Playing Through Receiver</option>
            <option value="arm bar">arm bar</option>
            <option value="Grabbing">Grabbing</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div id="catILF" style="display:none;">
     <select name="category" id="ilfCategory" class='category' style="width:210px;">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="moving">Moving</option>
         <option value="illegal">Illegal</option>
          <option value="standing">Standing</option>                                           
     </select>
  </div>

  <div id="catOPI" style="display:none;">
    <select name="category" id="opiCategory" class='category' style="width:210px;">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="restrict">Restrict</option>
        <option value="holding">Holding</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

The foulTypes .change function is working and the correct div is being displayed.  The problem I am having is when I submit the form.  If the #catDPI is visible the category menu selected value is submitted fine.  If #catILF or #catOPI is visible the value for category is blank.  I am not using the Ids of the category menus.

```
  $("#submit-foul").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var category = $(".category").val();

    var dataString = 'category=' + category;

    if($("#submit-foul").valid()){
       $.ajax({
          url: 'myUrl',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
              if(data == 1){
                 alert('Success');
              };
          }
       });
     }
     return false;
  });
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Time to send it to the experts!!  I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Where is your `<form action="action.php">` tag?

Comment: I am submitting via ajax.  You can see the .submit function.  Here is my form tag - <form id="submit-foul" action="#" method="post" name="submit-foul">

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? is a little difficult to find the error

Comment: `var category = $(".category").val();` is going to return the value of the first element with `class="category"` (not the one that enabled and visible)

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right, so in my example below I added a class to use flag.

Comment: @user2091928, One option would be to define `var $divSelectedCategory;` as a global variable and then use `var category = $divSelectedCategory.find('.category').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change function "foulTypes" and add class in visible select.

```
foulTypes.change(function () {
        //We first disable all, so we dont submit data for more than 1 category
        $("#catDPI, #catILF, #catOPI, #catOH, #catDH, #catILD, #catUNS, #catUNR, #catTGT").hide().find(".category").attr("disabled", true);
        var $divSelectedCategory;
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            $divSelectedCategory = $("#catDPI");
            $('#catDPI').show();
            $('#dpiCategory').addClass("visible");
        } else {
            $('#catDPI').hide();
            $('#dpiCategory').removeClass("visible")
        }

        .... CONTINUE
```

In your ajax submit..

```
var category = $(".category.visible").val();
```

Comment: I think that with this css trick you get a value of visible select. But this method not is the best form to send data .

Comment: The .hide() and .show() is working fine.  If foulTypes changes the correct div and category select menu is displayed.  It is the option value that is selected on the visible category that doesn't come through.

Comment: not understand my idea. If you add this class, does not affect to be displayed or not, but serves to select the select is actually visible, the name of the class is for reference only. In your example, when you get the value of .category has many selects the category class.

Comment: It is similar to making $ (".category:visible") but nose if you will work this css attribute to this case. Complete the rest of the example and try it! https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/